# Read Sharepoint list items from 2013 version and display in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server

I would like to retrieve SP 2013 list items from sharepoint online in javascript or client side.

Pls suggest possible ways. i have used spservices jquery library  but it is not working even though i have passed the credentails.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="/sites/test/SiteAssets/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="/sites/test/SiteAssets/jquery.SPServices-2014.02.min.js"></script>
<html>
<div><button onclick="getsite()" id="button">Test site access </button> </div>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

$.support.cors = "true";
alert("test");


function GetSite()
{

$().SPServices({
    operation: "Login",
    async: false,
    webURL: "https://url", //Site collection URL which has the required List data
    username: "username",
    password: "password",
    completefunc: function(xData, Status) 
        {
           alert('Status: '+status);
        }
     }     
  );


}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say we can do it in couple of ways:

**Approach 1:**

1. Use the PowerAutomate (Microsoft Flow). Refer to the below articles how to connect to SharePoint on-premise:

[Accessing on premise SharePoint site with flow](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Accessing-on-premise-SharePoint-site-with-flow/td-p/264783)

[Support for on-premises SharePoint lists](https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/support-for-sharepoint-on-premises/)

**Approach 2:**

If you have Nintex 365 workflow, create a site workflow and configure that as job.

**Approach 3:**

Create a PowerShell script and configure that in Windows task scheduler.

**Approach 4:**

Use the traditional REST API service.

**Notes** :

From the four approaches, PowerShell  is easiest one and less cost effective which I have been using.

Comment: can you pls share rest api samples to